# MongoDB Collection Record Count byt Group

Tags: mongodb

I an new to MongoDb and I have a MngoDB Collection which contain following records.

```
Name    Subject
AA  A
AA  B
AA  A
AA  C
AA  A
BB  A
BB  B
BB  B
CC  A
CC  C
DD  C
```

Using above record set i want to get the below output

```
Name    Subject Count
AA  A   3
AA  B   1
AA  C   1
BB  A   1
BB  B   2
CC  A   1
CC  C   1
DD  C   1
```

Please kindly help me to solve the issue

Comment: How do you come up with the number on the right? What kind of calculation is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation framework.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $group : { _id : {name:"$name"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } } ] );
```

More Details: [Clock here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#examples)

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate operation group documents on basis of specific field values  and apply operations on group data

Please try executing following query as an alternate solution

```
  db.collection.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $group: {
      _id:{name:'$name',subject:'$subject'},
      total:{$sum:1}
      }
    }

  ]
);
```

For more detailed  description regarding **aggregation** please refer the documentation as mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/